# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Number)'

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

**This program can't compile by Xcode, it only run in IOS application "Playgrounds".**

In IOS application "Playgrounds" -> "Learn to Code 3"(Swift 3.1) ->"Music Universe" I have below code:

```
// A touch event for when your finger is moving across the scene.

// Declaration
struct Touch

// The position of this touch on the scene.

// Declaration
var position: Point

// The x coordinate for the point.

// Declaration for touch.position.x
var x: Double
```

The above just for explanation.

```
let touch: Touch
let numberOfNotes = 16
let normalizedXPosition = (touch.position.x + 500) / 1000
let note = normalizedXPosition * (numberOfNotes - 1)
let index = Int(note)
```

The last sentence show error:
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Number)'.
How can I convert `note` to `Int` type?

Comment: What type has `touch.position.x`? – A *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: For the first look, I thought that `touch.position.x` type is CGFloat, but it seems it is not because you should get an compile-time error on `let note = normalizedXPosition * (numberOfNotes - 1)`, complaining about multiplying between Int and CGFloat.

Comment: I have add the comment of touch.position.x, the touch.position.x type is `Double`

Comment: Your updated code does not compile (missing braces after "struct Touch", undefined type "Point"). But if touch.position.x is a Double then the line `let note =  ...` would already fail to compile.

Comment: Well, then I assume that you should get an error on the line of `let note = normalizedXPosition * (numberOfNotes - 1)`, complaining about: cannot apply `*` between Double and Int...

Comment: This didn't a complete program, I just want show you the question simplicity. These code run in "Playgrounds", I didn't compile it. Only the `let index = Int(note)` have error.

Comment: @linjie: As you may have noticed, we cannot reproduce your exact error. I would suggest that you  copy the relevant code into a *new* project in order to create a [mcve].

Comment: @MartinR These code only can run in IOS application "Playgrounds", you can try "Learn to Code 3"(Swift 3.1) ->"Music Universe" in "Playgrounds", then you can reproduce this error. I have updated the question say that these code can't compile by Xcode, only can run in IOS application "Playgrounds". I have get the answer, you can see that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is running on the iPad application *Swift Playgrounds*.

They apparently have created a `protocol` `Number` behind the scenes to ease the pain of Swift type conversions.  In this mini program, it is possible to multiply an `Int` and a `Double` without first converting the `Int` to a `Double`:

```
let a = 5      // a is an Int
let b = 6.3    // b is a Double
let c = a * b  // This results in c being type Number
```

`Number` has read-only properties `int` and `double` which return the `Int` and `Double` representations of the number.

```
var int: Int { get }
var double: Double { get }
```

So, if you need `index` to be an `Int`, do it like this:

```
let index = note.int
```